# visual svn / tortoise svn authentication issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I setup visual SVN on windows server 2008 named *myserver* It asked me to create a username/password since I selected **Subversion Authentication**.  I then created an empty repository called myproject.

I also installed tortoise svn on my Dev box Windows 7 and trying to access with repository browser http://*myserver*:8080/svn/myproject/ however it gives me the same error all the time.

> "OPTIONS of 'http://*myserver*:8080/svn/myproject/' Could not read
>   status line: An existing connection was closed by the remote host.
>   http://*myserver*:8080/"

I also tried windows basic with the same result.  What's missing here?

Also when I try to browse to http://*myserver*:8080/svn/ it says "Repository moved permanently to 'http://myserver:8080/'; please relocate"

Is this some sort of permissions issue?

One more thing - when I navigate to 'http://*myserver*:8080/svn/myproject/' on my web browser it asks me for the user/password and lets me browse the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had to specify the ip address in server bindings.  once i did that all worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I also install VisualSVN in Windows Server 2003(ESERVER,222.200.164.202), use TortoiseSVN in local Windows 7. And I choose Using **Subversion Authentication** as well.

For the whole Repositories, or the repository call "myproject", check your account has the right to access.

Using https instead of http. VisualSVN suggest using https instead of http. VisualSVN may prevent access thought http.

All of All, try https plz. :)

Comment: how do I check permissions you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

1. For Subversion Authentication (in VisualSVN Server) you **must** create at least 1 user in Management Console and give him appropriate permissions for repo|repos
2. Check for must-have files  in repo-root
   htpasswd (contain users and digestedpasswords)
   authz (groups and path-based ACLs)

> when I try to browse to http://myserver:8080/svn/ it says "Repository moved permanently to 'http://myserver:8080/'; please relocate"
>   Is this some sort of permissions issue?

No, it's configuration issue for Location. Anyway, best way to find correct URL for repo inside VisualSVN server is Copy URL from repo context-menu in management console